# WSO2: How to change "Account Management Policies" specifically "Lock Idle Accounts" through Java API

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0 and I am creating tenants using WSO2 TenantMgtAdminServiceStub API.

I would like to set "Account Management Policies" specifically "Lock Idle Accounts" setting in Resident Identity Provider through JAVA API while creating tenant.

Answer (score 2):

You could use updateResidentIdP method from https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityProviderMgtService?wsdl soap service.

Sample soap request will be as follows.

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.idp.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:xsd="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
       <soap:Header/>
      <soap:Body>
      <mgt:updateResidentIdP>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mgt:identityProvider>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:alias>?</xsd:alias>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:certificate></xsd:certificate>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:claimConfig>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:alwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>false</xsd:alwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->


               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:localClaimDialect>false</xsd:localClaimDialect>
               <!--Optional:-->

            </xsd:claimConfig>
           <xsd:homeRealmId>localhost</xsd:homeRealmId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:identityProviderName>LOCAL</xsd:identityProviderName>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <xsd:idpProperties>
               <!--Optional:-->

               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:name>suspension.notification.AlreadyWritten</xsd:name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:value>true</xsd:value>
            </xsd:idpProperties>
            <xsd:idpProperties>
               <!--Optional:-->

               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:name>suspension.notification.account.disable.delay</xsd:name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:value>10</xsd:value>
            </xsd:idpProperties>
            <xsd:idpProperties>
               <!--Optional:-->

               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:name>suspension.notification.enable</xsd:name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xsd:value>true</xsd:value>
            </xsd:idpProperties>
            <!--Optional:-->


            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:primary>true</xsd:primary>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

         </mgt:identityProvider>
      </mgt:updateResidentIdP>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Since you wanted to use it through JAVA API, import org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub in the project and invoke updateResidentIdP operation with the required parameters. Since you are using 5.3.0, use 5.7.5 version of the stub
if you are using maven, you can use the maven dependency as

```
<groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
<artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub</artifactId>
<version>5.7.5</version>
```